# How do I get Pygame rendering to work for my neural network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pygame

I'm trying to build a neural network to play snake. Here's the training code:

```
def train(self):
    self.build_model()
    for episode in range(self.max_episodes):
        self.current_episode = episode
        env = SnakeEnv(self.screen)
        episode_reward = 0
        for timestep in range(self.max_steps):
            env.render(self.screen)
            state = env.get_state()
            action = None
            epsilon = self.current_eps
            if epsilon > random.random():
                action = np.random.choice(env.action_space) #explore
            else:
                values = self.policy_model.predict(env.get_state()) #exploit
                action = np.argmax(values)
            #print(action)
            experience = env.step(action)
            if(experience['done'] == True):
                break
            episode_reward += experience['reward']
            if(experience['done'] == True):
                continue
            if(len(self.memory) < self.memory_size):
                self.memory.append(Experience(experience['state'], experience['action'], experience['reward'], experience['next_state']))
            else:
                self.memory[self.push_count % self.memory_size] = Experience(experience['state'], experience['action'], experience['reward'], experience['next_state'])
            self.push_count += 1
            self.decay_epsilon(episode)
            if self.can_sample_memory():
                memory_sample = self.sample_memory()
                #q_pred = np.zeros((self.batch_size, 1))
                #q_target = np.zeros((self.batch_size, 1))
                #i = 0
                for memory in memory_sample:
                    memstate = memory.state
                    action = memory.action
                    next_state = memory.next_state
                    reward = memory.reward
                    max_q = reward + self.discount_rate * self.replay_model.predict(next_state)
                    #q_pred[i] = q_value
                    #q_target[i] = max_q
                    #i += 1
                    self.policy_model.fit(memstate, max_q, epochs=1, verbose=0)
            env.render(self.screen)
        print("Episode: ", episode, " Total Reward: ", episode_reward)
        if episode % self.target_update == 0:
            self.replay_model.set_weights(self.policy_model.get_weights())
    pygame.quit()
```

The screen initialization code looks like this:

```
pygame.init()
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")
```

The environment rendering code looks like this:

```
def render(self, screen):
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for i in range(20):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, 30*i), (600, 30*i))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (30*i, 0), (30*i, 600))
    self.food.render()
    self.snake.render()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

The food and snake render methods just draw simple squares at the appropriate coordinates. When I run the training code, I just get a white screen. When I end the program by hitting ctrl C, I see the screen rendered properly for a brief moment and then it abruptly closes. How do I get it to render properly?

Comment: Why is there a `pygame.quit()` in your training function ?

Comment: @Kingsley after the training is done, there's no need for the window to be open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code may work on annother OS, but generally, you have to let pygame process your window manager's events by calling `pygame.event.get()` (or `.pump()`). Otherwise, nothing will be drawn on the screen.

So, in your loop, you should process the events in the event queue, and at least handle the `QUIT` event, e.g.:

```
def render(self, screen):
    ...
    # or create a new function, it's up to you, just to this once per frame
    events = pygame.events.get()
    for e in events:
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit() # or whatever to quit the program
```

You coud also do more fancy things to seperate your training code and the drawing code, like using callbacks or coroutines, but that's another topic.